# Obtain the covariance matrix with the correlations and the variances

Tags: normalization, joint-distribution

i have the following problem that makes me crazy.
COnsider a trivariate normal variable, let $\sigma_1^2$, $\sigma_2^2$ and $\sigma_3^2$ be the variance of the three components and $\rho_{1,2}$, $\rho_{1,3}$ and $\rho_{2,3}$ be the correlation coefficients between the components. I want to obtain the covariance matrix of the trivarate normal variable. For me it is a really simple task but there is something wrong....

The covariance matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_1^2 &   \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho_{1,2} &   \sigma_1 \sigma_3 \rho_{1,3} \\
\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho_{1,2} &  \sigma_2^2  &   \sigma_2 \sigma_3 \rho_{2,3} \\
\sigma_1 \sigma_3 \rho_{1,3} & \sigma_2 \sigma_3 \rho_{2,3} & \sigma_3^2
\end{array} \right)
$$
but if i use the following value $\sigma_1^2=1$, $\sigma_2^2=1$, $\sigma_3^2=3$, $\rho_{1,2}=0.9$, $\rho_{1,3}=-0.9$ and $\rho_{2,3}=0.1$, the covariance matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0.9 & -1.5588457 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.1732051\\
-1.558846 &0.1732051 & 3 
\end{array} \right)
$$
is not positive definite.

It seem strange to me...

Comment: Since you chose your six values arbitrarily the matrix is not guaranteed to be positive definite. With real data, the values are not totally free: with some values fixed, other values can vary only within some bounds. This insures that the matrix will be positive definite.

Comment: In particular, your correlation matrix is already not positive definite. With r12=0.9 and r13=-0.9, r23=0.1 is unrealistic. r23 should be -.62 or more negative.

Comment: @ttnphns this would make a nice answer :)